# how can I get my file directory / file path when file selected by input in react or html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I selected file and put it in state - everything about file object work properly but the
but the webkitRelativePath is null ,

```
     <input type="file" onChange={changeHandler} id="main_img" name="img" style{{display:'none'}} webkitdirectory  />//this my input

state{//this is my state
  name:"1112.PNG"
  lastModified:1645438409236
  lastModifiedDate:Mon Feb 21 2022 13:43:29 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)
  webkitRelativePath:""
  size:1158291
  type:"image/png"
  arrayBuffer:ƒ arrayBuffer() {}
  slice:ƒ slice() {}
  stream:ƒ stream() {}
  text:ƒ text() {}
}
```

this object is that get from input-- why webkit is empty ?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, you can't get full path of a file with JavaScript. For security reasons this is not allowed in most browsers.

**webkitRelativePath** only works in Chrome. This allows a user to select a folder instead of files, and every single file is read recursively. The webkitRelativePath contains the relative path of the file within the hierarchy.